# Automatically fill a lookup field on an object based on field in another lookup object

Tags: trigger, lookup, configuration

I have an object `Call` which has a lookup field to `Tactic` object.There is another lookup `Account Plan` on `Call` which looks up to `Account Plan` object. The Tactic object also has a lookup to object `Account Plan`. 
What I'm trying to do here is, when a user records a call, he will manually fill in the lookup `Tactic__c` in call with a value say T1, and if the Account Plan lookup in T1 is A1, this will be automatically populated in `Account_Plan__c` on `Call2__c`.

For example, a user creates a call, selects Tactic as Tactic1. For Tactic1 record, the Account plan value is AP1. So on saving the call, the value in Account plan for this call will be automatically populated as AP1.

For this, I have created a formula field on `Call2__c` called `Formula_Plan__c` which stores the Account plan from Tactic: `CORE_Tactic__r.Account_Plan__c`. I've written the following trigger on `Call2__c` using this field:

```
trigger AccountPlanUpdateItem on Call2__c (before update, before insert) {

    List<Call2__c> callList = [SELECT id, Account_Plan__c,Formula_Plan__c FROM Call2__c];

    Map<String, Call2__c> shippingNumToContactMap = new Map<String, Call2__c>();

    for (call2__c c : callList) {
        shippingNumToContactMap.put(c.Formula_Plan__c, c);
    }

    for (call2__c o : Trigger.new) {
        if (o.Formula_Plan__c != null) {
            o.Account_Plan__c = shippingNumToContactMap.get(o.Formula_Plan__c).Formula_Plan__c;
        }
        else {
            o.Account_Plan__c = null;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, the first time I create a call, the trigger caused the error:

> AccountPlanUpdateItem:execution of BeforeInsert caused by:SystemNullPointerException:Attempt to de-reference a null object Trigger.AccountPlanUpdateItem:line 14 column 1.

I've tried a few ways but the lookup field on call remains blank.

Comment: formula field is calculated after saving the record. There could be a flaw in your design. can you post what is the exact requirement, so that community members could guide you properly.

Comment: I want to populate the lookup field Account_Plan__c on Call2__c as per the Account_Plan__c value on the object Tactic__c, which corresponds to the Tactic selected on the call. Yes, you're right and it was on my mind that probably the issue of formula field being null when first the record is being inserted, might be the problem. I have tried to directly populate the lookup on Call by querying the Account Plan on Tactic object(without using formula field on call), but the lookup field Account_plan__c on Call2__c remains blank. Please help if possible.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post with any clarifications, rather than putting them in the comments. Makes the updates much more accessible and permanent.